# i am facing error while installing PySimpleGUI

Tags: pysimplegui

```
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pysimplegui/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pysimplegui/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1007)'))) - skipping
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1007)'))) - skipping

WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1007)'))': /simple/pysimplegui/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1007)'))': /simple/pysimplegui/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1007)'))': /simple/pysimplegui/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1007)'))': /simple/pysimplegui/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1007)'))': /simple/pysimplegui/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PySimpleGUI (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for PySimpleGUI
```

I am not sure what I need to do

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please re-read [ask] and provide some more detail, for example which command you've been executing to get that output. It looks like it can't verify the certificate for pypi.org. That can have many reasons from locally misconfigured (or just outdated) CA lists, to someone intercepting your network traffic (company or state firewall) or (theoretically) a problem on pypi.org side, but I can access that page, so that's probably not it. Can you run something like `curl https://pypi.org`?

Comment: Maybe you need to install SSL certificates for python, these should be in your python install location. Run python 3.X/Install Certificates.command